# Persist environment variable for a Rails app on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, environment-variables, digital-ocean

How can I persist environment variables for my Rails app hosted on Digital Ocean?

Locally I run a bash script with commands like, `export SERVICE_USERNAME='somekey'`.

But when I try to manually run `export SERVICE_USERNAME='somekey'`, while ssh-ing onto the Ubuntu server, they only last for the session... which is not helpful for my app.

How can I persist environment variables on Digital Ocean? Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either set your environment variables to the user (in the ~/.profile or ~./pam_environment files of the user) or system wide (in the /etc/environment file)

You can find more info on this [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

EDIT;

You could have your script to do this:

```
sudo echo 'export SERVICE_USERNAME="somekey"' >> /etc/environment
```

Comment: I think I need to store them system wide so the app can function (ie: S3 keys), but running the above command gives `-bash: /etc/environment: Permission denied` even with `sudo`. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Could you try this : `ls -lsh /etc/environment` and check who the file belongs to?

Comment: Needed to add as root. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!