# Where to store master.key for Rails 5.2+ app on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, digital-ocean, credentials

Is there a best practise regarding where to put `master.key` for a Rails 5.2 app on Digital Ocean?

Background:

- Rails 5.2 allows storing sensitive variables in a file called `credentials.yml.enc`
- `credentials.yml.enc` is encrypted by another file called `master.key`
- You shouldn't put the `master.key` anywhere public or push to Github
- But the app needs it to decrypt and access variables in `credentials.yml.enc`

On Heroku, it's as easy as creating a environment variable called `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` in the Heroku UI, but it's not so straightforward for Digital Ocean.

I'm just deploying with git hooks. Nothing special and no CI/CD.

Should I just hardcode the `master.key` in `.bashrc` or something? (it feels a little sketchy)

Comment: I am on Heroku also but I guess Digital Ocean are bare metal servers ? What Os are you running ? If you run a Ubuntu server then I guess this thread can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615522/persist-environment-variable-for-a-rails-app-on-digital-ocean You just have to expose the environment variable so it is available at OS level. also do you use Foreman gem to start all services ? This man page http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/ at "environment" explains Foreman can expose your environement variables. Just add a .env file with your master key. (dont version it to git)

Comment: (nothing of the above has been tried yet here as I am still on Heroku for my main app, but I hope this can direct you)